# Multiple regression, reshaping inputs with multiple independent variables

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scikit-learn, regression

I am doing multiple regression on my data, but plotting the data throws an error: `ValueError: x and y must be the same size`.

```
x.shape is (10000, 2) 
#Since I have two independent  x = dataset[['green', 'blue']]

y.shape is (10000,)
```

how can I reshape the arrays? since I have two independent variables in x.

Code:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('colors.csv')


x = dataset[['green', 'blue']] #independent variable
y = dataset['value']


x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 100)


mlr = LinearRegression()
mlr.fit(x_train, y_train)


print("Intercept: ", mlr.intercept_)
print("Coefficients:")
list(zip(x, mlr.coef_))

#Prediction of test set
y_pred_mlr= mlr.predict(x_test)
#Predicted values
print ("input test set", x_test)
print("Prediction for test set: {}".format(y_pred_mlr))

mlr_diff = pd.DataFrame({'Actual value': y_test, 'Predicted value': y_pred_mlr})


plt.scatter(x_train, y_train,color='g')
plt.plot(x_train, mlr.predict(x_train),color='k')

plt.show()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this problem, you need to scatter each dimension in one plot.

maybe this code help you:

```py
color = ['g','b']
plot_number = 1
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (15,5))
for i in range(x_train.shape[1]):
    ax, plot_number = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, plot_number), plot_number+1
    ax.scatter(x_train.iloc[:,i], y_train, color=color[i])
    ax.set_xlabel("x_train", fontsize = 18)
    ax.set_ylabel("Y", rotation = 0, fontsize = 18)
plt.show()
```

output like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using a scatter plot which expect two 1-D array (for `x` and `y` axis).

You can solve this problem by:

- Use a 3-D plot

  ```
   ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
   ax.scatter3D(X_train[:,0], X_train[:,1], y_pred)
  ```
- create 2-D plot for each feature against `y_pred`

  ```
   fig, axs = plt.subplots(2)
   for i in range(X_train.shape[1]):
       axs[i].scatter(X_train[:,i], y_pred)
  ```